# JHipster and React: How to call function after calling asynchronous reducer action?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jhipster, react-thunk

Use Case: I have a react application generated with JHipster. I need to get data from API, map to form contract, and then submit the form.

Problem: JHipster generated reducer code doesn't return a promise, so how do I know when a reducer action is finished? How can I call a function after getting an entity to update state?

Getting Entity and Returning the ICrudGetAction:

```
export interface IPayload<T> { // redux-action-type.ts (JHipster Code from  node_modules)
  type: string;
  payload: AxiosPromise<T>;
  meta?: any;
}
export type IPayloadResult<T> = ((dispatch: any) => IPayload<T> | Promise<IPayload<T>>);
export type ICrudGetAction<T> = (id: string | number) => IPayload<T> | ((dispatch: any) => IPayload<T>);

// Start of my reducer code 
export default (state: AdState = initialState, action): AdState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUEST(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MYENTITY_LIST):
      return {
        ...state,
        errorMessage: null,
        updateSuccess: false,
        loading: true
      };
    case FAILURE(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MYENTITY_LIST):
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        updating: false,
        updateSuccess: false,
        errorMessage: action.payload
      };
    case SUCCESS(ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_MYENTITY_LIST): {
      const links = parseHeaderForLinks(action.payload.headers.link);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        links,
        entities: loadMoreDataWhenScrolled(state.entities, action.payload.data, links),
        totalItems: parseInt(action.payload.headers['x-total-count'], 10)
      };
    }
    case ACTION_TYPES.RESET:
      return {
        ...initialState
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export const getEntity: ICrudGetAction<IMyEntity> = id => {
  const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}/${id}`;
  return {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ENTITY,
    payload: axios.get<IMyEntity>(requestUrl)
  };
};
```

I try to do this and it works but gives me compile errors:

```
this.props.getEntity(this.props.match.params.id).then((response) => {
    // Map to form attributes and call setState
});
```

I get error message: 
**TS2339: Property 'then' does not exist on type 'IPayload | ((dispatch: any) => IPayload)'.
  Property 'then' does not exist on type 'IPayload'.**

This makes sense because we are not returning a promise. but how can I update the code to return a promise such that I don't break all the things that were autogenerated while also keeping the redux store updated?